# Cruise control - adding diagnostic logging

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

In Cruise control is there a way to log the description for a test step?

```
     <exec>
        <executable>$(cmd)</executable>
        <baseDirectory>bin\$(bit)\Release</baseDirectory>
        <buildArgs>/C del /Q /F /S *.*</buildArgs>
        <description>Cleaning up the release directory</description>
     </exec>
```

I notice the description does not end up in our log file?
Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: What would the reason be for adding the description to the log?

Comment: For debugging purposes.  To make it easy to identify which step failed.

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl includes the details/specification of the task before any of the output; such as:

```
 ...
 <buildresults>
   <task>
      <buildArgs>/c "echo hello"</buildArgs>
      <buildTimeoutSeconds>1800</buildTimeoutSeconds>
      <baseDirectory>c:\</baseDirectory>
      <description>description</description>
      <dynamicValues/>
      <environment/>
      <executable>c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe</executable>
      <priority>Normal</priority>
      <successExitCodes/>
   </task>
   <message>hello</message>
   ...
 <buildresults>
 ...
```

This also includes the description of the task.
If the task fails, I believe the the exception text is included as text within the `buildresults` node